# Make swagger display action URL in camel case

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

If I have an action defined as (note - all names are hypothetical)

```cs
[HttpGet("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public string LogMeIn(...)
```

Swagger will generate URL as `.../api/Auth/LogMeIn`

[image]

I've added option

```cs
services.AddRouting(opt => opt.LowercaseUrls = true)
```

This got me to this point in the swagger `.../api/auth/logmein`

But I need to be at `camelCase` -->  `.../api/auth/logMeIn`

I've tried to look through swagger options, app options, but no luck. What can I do here? BTW, searched the internet. Mostly they talk about parameters/models. This is swagger UI URL. Thanks

Comment: why is this specific requirement to have url in camelcase only for swagger? why don't you change the api itself to camelCase.

Comment: @CodingMytra We're keeping up with coding standards for c# - controller is a class and should be PascalCase. Potentially, the route can be defined as `[HttpGet("api/someController/someAction")]. This however, defeats purpose of the tokens, i.e. `[controller]`. But in the swagger, we have a requirement to have camelCase for the URLs.

Comment: you just want to change display name for API or really change the url only in swagger. if you change url then how will you call your api from swagger. then it will defeat the whole purpose of having swagger

Comment: this is not a case sensitive URL. And I am not changing that. I only want it to display in camelCase in swagger

Comment: can you put screenshot of swagger where are you expecting it to change

Comment: @CodingMytra please see ^^^^

Comment: i have provided a possible solution. check it below

Comment: next challenge would be to convert any string to camel case for that you need to define some delimiter but with strings like "weatherforecast" it would be difficult as it does not have clear delimiter. so if you are able to write a logic to convert anystring to camel case then good to use the code I  provided in my ans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i don't know if something inbuilt is available or not but you can write a simple document filter like this.

```
    public class UrlRenameDocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
        {
            OpenApiPaths keyValuePairs = new OpenApiPaths();
            foreach(var path in swaggerDoc.Paths)
            {
                var value = path.Value;

                // here you have to put logic to convert name to camelCase
                string newkey = ConvertToCamelCase(path.Key);

                keyValuePairs.Add(newkey, value);
            }
            swaggerDoc.Paths = keyValuePairs;
        }
    }
```

in program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(o =>
{
    o.DocumentFilter<UrlRenameDocumentFilter>();
});
```

Comment: Super. I tried in the manual mode - swagger page looks great. Don't know if this will cause any problems but it does it. And All I need now is to write a regex to get tokens and change them. Thanks a lot.